# QuantumGIS EPSG:3857 doesn't match with Leaflet

Tags: qgis, leaflet, qgis-openlayers-plugin

Leaflet documentation said that they have EPSG:3857 as default projection.

Using QGIS with OpenLayers plugin, I point to a location to find it's coordinate. I used EPSG:3857 in QGIS as well.

The problem is, the location doesn't match. I know that the location in Leaflet using "lat-long" format, while location in QGIS is using "long-lat" format.

Leaflet documentation said that it used "degree", while (I don't quite sure) I think QGIS use decimal.

Does anybody has experience with this? What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The mismatch, is due to the different projections used for the coordinates.

In Leaflet, the Map is in EPSG:3857, while the coordinates used for various things are in LatLong (EPSG:4326).

In OpenStreetMaps Layer in Qgis, the map and the coordinates both are in EPSG:3857.

So when you see [image] in QGIS, these coordinates are in EPSG:3857 with units meters.

You will need to project the coordinates from Web Mercator to WGS84. I don't have much experience with leaflet, but you could have a look at the [proj4js](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/) Library.

Comment: I also use EPSG:3857 for QGIS. This is indicated by the bottom-right box, isn't it?

Comment: You are correct. Whenever you add a layer from the OpenLayers Plugin, the coordinate system for QGIS is changed to EPSG 3857

Comment: Keep in mind that the EPSG:3857 units are not real metres. They match only at the equator with metres, and get squuezed the more to the poles you come.

Comment: @AndreJoost: My location is near to equator. So I think it shouldn't differ that much